# nodejs Traverse (js-traverse) module: How to 'break' traversing

Tags: node.js, traversal

How to break/stop traversal in nodejs traverse module?

I am traversing a json and on certain condition, I want to stop traversing.

`traverse(req.body).forEach(function (xnode) {
         log.info("Inspecting node: "+xnode);
         ...
         ...
         //If JSON Threat is detected, return error
         if(Object.keys(err).length > 0){
             return next(new Error(JSON.stringify(err)));
             //traversing should halt here but it continues 
             //DO I need to explicitly break it?
          }
    });`

During debugging, I observed the return statement sends control to calling (connect) middleware but traverse continues in background. I didn't find any break/stop options in docs. How to stop traversing after the error occures?

Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is this.stop() method in traverse module to stop traversing the object. Although this method is not mentioned in module documentation.

```
traverse(obj).forEach(function (x) {
    console.log("key: "+this.key+"\tValue: "+x+"\tLevel: "+this.level);
    if(this.key==='b'){
        console.log("Halting Traversal: "+this.key+" value: "+x);
        this.stop();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.some` instead of `.forEach`.  This will loop, but it will stop looping as soon as you return `true`.

```
if (Object.keys(err).length > 0) {
    next(new Error(JSON.stringify(err));
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but Traverse (https://www.npmjs.com/package/traverse) doesn't have .some() method.